# Evaluate method returns a one element array rather than a value

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a function that copies some data from one workbook to another. After opening the destination workbook, the function evaluates a name that is present in the destination workbook.

```vb
Dim destWb As Workbook
Dim destEndRow As Long

Set destWb = GetWorkbook

destEndRow = Evaluate(destWb.Names("EndRow").Value) //This line produces error #13
```

The formula for EndRow:

```
=ROW(Sheet1!$B$113)-2
```

I have used the evaluate method on other names and in other projects, but I've never had it exhibit this behavior. Usually it returns the value that the formula in the name evaluates to.
Also, I know that 113-2 = 111, but the destination workbook may have rows deleted/inserted above row 113. The name allows for dynamic referencing of the end row in my data set.

The error was thrown because the Evaluate method is returning an array with one element (x(1 to 1)) instead of the value that EndRow produces.

The code works if I replace the last line with:

```
destEndRow = Evaluate(destWb.Names("EndRow").Value) (1) //This line works fine
```

Comment: `ROW` returns an array when evaluated